# passing deferred into a jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to figure out jQuery's deferred api using the docs together with code that someone else wrote but find it very confusing. I wonder if looking at the functions below, you coudl explain

1. what is the significance of dfd.resolve. Does it mean that the fadeOut is complete i.e. is it only executed once the fadeOut is complete? Is this passing the deferred object into the jQuery fadeOut function?
2. what happens when promise.promise(); is returned? Why call promise(); on the promise property?

   Can you please explain this code a little

   ```
   hide: function() {
           if (this.el.is(":visible") === false) {
               return null;
           }
           promise = $.Deferred(_.bind(function(dfd) {
               this.el.fadeOut('fast', dfd.resolve)}, this));
           return promise.promise();
       },
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right. `dfd.resolve` is passed as the callback to `fadeOut`, so that when the fade out is complete, the promise will resolve.

`promise = $.Deferred` is misleading, since `$.Deferred` returns a `Deferred` object, not a promise. Calling `.promise()` on the deferred will return a promise.

The difference between a deferred and a promise is that the promise is only used for registering callbacks (via `always`, `done`, `fail`, `pipe`, `progress`, or `then`), whereas the original deferred object also has a `resolve` method.

**To summarize**: a `promise` is the same as the original `deferred`, minus the `resolve` method (and its related methods). This is used to protect your `promise`, so that you're the only one with the ability to resolve/reject it. All the caller can do is add callback functions to it.

Here's [a quote from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/):

> The `deferred.promise()` method allows an asynchronous function to prevent other code from interfering with the progress or status of its internal request. The Promise exposes only the Deferred methods needed to attach additional handlers or determine the state (`then`, `done`, `fail`, `always`, `pipe`, `progress`, and `state`), but not ones that change the state (`resolve`, `reject`, `notify`, `resolveWith`, `rejectWith`, and `notifyWith`).

---

To simplify this, let's remove the underscore binding:

```
function hide () {
  var deferred = $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    $('div').fadeOut('slow', dfd.resolve)
  });

  return deferred.promise();
}

hide().then(function () {
  alert('Fade out is done!');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fDUej/

Comment: this is code to hide a view element. In that context, what would it mean for the "promise to resolve". What's triggered when promise(); runs?  but what is the promise that is returned? something must happen? what?

Comment: does calling promise(); trigger dfd.resolve? if so, what might happen then?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil - Nothing happens when the promise is resolved, unless you register a callback on that promise.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil - calling `promise()` _removes_ `.resolve` from the deferred object. (in fact, it just returns a different object with a subset of methods that are available to normal deferred)

Comment: @c69 - Which is exactly what I said. *...the promise is **only** used for registering callbacks, whereas the original deferred object **has a resolve** method*.

Comment: so promise() is basically telling hide().then function that it can run?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil - `promise` doesn't do anything. For all intents and purposes, you could just return the deferred itself. Returning a promise instead is just to protect your deferred, so that it can't be resolved by the caller.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/ -  `The Promise exposes only the Deferred methods needed to attach additional handlers or determine the state (then, done, fail, always, pipe, progress, and state), but not ones that change the state (resolve, reject, notify, resolveWith, rejectWith, and notifyWith).` -  @JosephSilber _you edited answer faster, than i typed my comment_ ;)

Comment: @c69 - Thanks for the quote. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @JosephSilber thanx :) now it looks nice and will serve future generations ;)

Comment: thanks, I read the docs already, but it's a little abstract for a relatively inexperienced developer. I was hoping for more plain language.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil - I was under the impression that you already knew what a deferred is. Was that a wrong assumption?

Comment: @JosephSilber I only sort of know what a deferred is in the sense of I don't know if I see the benefits vs. what would happen if a deferred wasn't used.

Comment: For the record - as written, this is an example of the "Deferred Anti-pattern". `hide()` can (and should) be written without creating a Deferred object, eg `hide: function() { return (!this.el.is(":visible")) ? null : this.el.fadeOut('fast').promise(); },`.